# How to debug a Slim Template?

Tags: ruby, slim-lang

I have a Bootstrap Table, built with Slim, using Ruby to populate the table with data.
Being new to Slim, I'm unsure as to how I can best debug it. As an example, in the table below I would like to look inside the loop, and take a closer look at whats being outputted.

Binding.pry has zero effect, so clearly I'm doing this wrong.

NB. I would like to be able to navigate line by line through this slim template, rather than simply debugging the source scripts.

```
  tbody.activities
  - @case_file_activities.each do |activity|
    tr
      - activity_cell = cell(:activity, activity)
      td: code == link_to(activity.slug, activity_cell.path)
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using slim tags?

```
    tbody.activities
    - @case_file_activities.each do |activity|
      - binding.pry
      tr
        - activity_cell = cell(:activity, activity)
        td: code == link_to(activity.slug, activity_cell.path)
```

in slim, `=` is a Ruby call that produces output, as in `<%= omgomg =%>`
and `-` is Ruby control code, as in `<% blabla %>`